# How to use GLES11Ext.glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES or say it EGLImage direct texture in Android,0x502 error?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I want to replace the glTexImage2D by using glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES in Android.I' ve read some information about how to use EGLImage or say it direct texture in Android.

And i found [this API in SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES11Ext.html#glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(int,%20java.nio.Buffer)).Buf when i try it in a demo encounted some problems,when i use this method i got a 0x502 error.

I use a simple GLSurfaceView in activity,and try to load bitmap in onSurfaceCreated when creating the texture.BTW,i use some code of google's grafika.

Here is the init code.

```
GLSurfaceView glSV = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.gl_sv);
glSV.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
DTSurfaceRender dtSurfaceRender = new DTSurfaceRender();
glSV.setRenderer(dtSurfaceRender);
glSV.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
```

Here is the Render code

```
class DTSurfaceRender implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private FullFrameRect mFullScreen;

    private final float[] mSTMatrix = new float[16];
    private int mTextureId;

    public DTSurfaceRender() {
        Matrix.setIdentityM(mSTMatrix, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl10) {
        mFullScreen.drawFrame(mTextureId, mSTMatrix);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl10, int i, int i1) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl10, EGLConfig eglConfig) {
        mFullScreen = new FullFrameRect(new Texture2dProgram(
                Texture2dProgram.ProgramType.TEXTURE_EXT));
        ByteBuffer data = ByteBuffer.allocate(mWidth * mHeight * 4);
        patternPixelSource(data, 1);
        mTextureId = mFullScreen.createImageTexture(data, mWidth, mHeight, GLES20.GL_RGBA);
    }
}
```

Here is the *createImageTexture* code

```
public int createImageTexture(ByteBuffer data, int width, int height, int format) {
    int[] textureHandles = new int[1];
    int textureHandle;

    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textureHandles, 0);
    textureHandle = textureHandles[0];
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glGenTextures");

    GLES20.glBindTexture(mTextureTarget, textureHandle);

    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
            GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,
            GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("glTexParameter");
    GLES11Ext.glEGLImageTargetTexture2DOES(GLES11Ext.GL_TEXTURE_EXTERNAL_OES, data);
    GlUtil.checkGlError("eglTargetTexture");

    return textureHandle;
}
```

In fact,about the texture tartget type whatever i use TEXTURE_2D or TEXTURE_EXT is both 0x502 error.